# redirect on theme switch - WordPress

Tags: plugins, settings-api

How to redirect on theme switch to my theme option page, what is the best to redirect wp_redirect or wp_safe_redirect:

here my code:

```
<?php
function sunset_add_admin_page() {
    //Generate Sunset Admin Page
    add_menu_page( 'Sunset Theme Options', 'Sunset', 'manage_options', 'alecaddd_sunset', 'sunset_theme_create_page', get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/sunset-icon.png', 110 );
    //Generate Sunset Admin Sub Pages
    add_submenu_page( 'alecaddd_sunset', 'Sunset Theme Options', 'General', 'manage_options', 'alecaddd_sunset', 'sunset_theme_create_page' );
    add_submenu_page( 'alecaddd_sunset', 'Sunset CSS Options', 'Custom CSS', 'manage_options', 'alecaddd_sunset_css', 'sunset_theme_settings_page');
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'sunset_add_admin_page' );
function sunset_sidebar_options( )
{
    echo "Customize your Sidebar Information";
}

function sunset_theme_create_page() {

}
function sunset_theme_settings_page( )
{
    echo "<h1> Hello Submenu </h1>";
}
function my_on_switch_theme($new_theme) {
    wp_safe_redirect( $location, $status );
    exit;
}
add_action('switch_theme', 'my_on_switch_theme');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`after_theme_switch`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_switch_theme) hook to do this, and `wp_safe_redirect()` works fine to redirect to local urls only. In your callback function check for the `$_GET['activated']` flag or you may get a "too many redirects" type of error.

```
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'my_theme_redirect' );
function my_theme_redirect() {
    if( isset( $_GET['activated'] ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( admin_url('admin.php?page=alecaddd_sunset') );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but what $_GET['activated'] mean?

Comment: and could you use wp_get_theme() instead of $_GET['activated'] or no?

Comment: @MoHamedHaSsn the `$_GET[‘activated’]` flag variable is set during the theme switch request(watch your URL bar when switching to another theme), and checking for it before using `wp_safe_redirect()` solved the “too many redirects” error I got without it. `wp_get_theme()` isn’t set during the theme switch request, so no it couldn’t be used like this. Did the answer work for you?

Comment: thank you, but there are a simple question, how to add class current when the page redirect like this image:
http://a.up-00.com/2017/11/151178045822291.png